# O notation using pseudocode

Tags: big-o

```
for i=1 to n       | n+1
  for j=1 to i^3   | ???
     x=x+1         |
```

Problem: Find O notation for n number of times the statement x=x+1 executes. 
I am confused with the second for loop here. I have the first statement that executes, n+1, but does the i=1 in the first for loop factor into the second for loop statement i^3?

My answer for this would be O=n+1.

Comment: When using O notation, you can ignore all the additive terms except the highest-order one; so `O(n+1)` is the same as `O(n)`. But that's not the right answer either.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I knew it was the leading terms that didn't matter. I figured it wasn't the answer. I am lost with what to do with the second step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i=1 to n
```

has obviously `n` iterations. In the second line:

```
for j=1 to i^3
```

each iteration runs `i^3` times. Since in each iteration `i` increases by 1, starting from 1 up to `n`, the running time of the algorithm can be expressed as the sum of all inner loop iterations:

```
Sum_i=1_i=n(i^3)
```

The summation equals:

```
(n^2 * (n + 1)^2) / 4
```

(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation and http://polysum.tripod.com for that.)

so you have:

```
O((n^2 * (n + 1)^2) / 4)
```

When simplifying the above as much as possible (remember that multiplication or division by non-zero constants, or addition with constants are to be ignored in big-oh notation) we get the answer:

```
O(n^4)
```

Comment: ahh yes the summations. Thank you.

Comment: It will give `O(n^7)` right? But if you see this way, inner loop runs for `1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + ... + n^3` times, giving `(n^2 * (n+1)^2)/4` times. which leaves us with `O(n^4)`. [What am I doing wrong here?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18896006/2260473)

Comment: @Panther I usually don't try to "visually" figure out big-o notations of loops. It gets my head spinning. I just do the math and trust the result. Unless of course the math itself contains a mistake. But if you think about it, i^7 isn't really too much, since you're raising `i` to the power of 3, which can produce quite large numbers.

Comment: I dont know I seem to get O(n^6) If addition, multiplcation and division of constants are ignored, i think that leaves `n^2 * (n)^3`.

Comment: @GiBiT09 I get n^7: n * (n * (n + 1) / 2)^3) = n * (n * n)^3 = n * n * n * n * n * n * n.

Comment: @NikosC. But the inner loop will be maximum n^3 and outer loop will be n times, which gives us `O(n^4)`, that's what I'm getting. I even tried the code, and its running for `(n^2 * (n+1)^2)/4` times, giving x value the same...

Comment: @GiBiT09, Panther : I got it wrong. The summation is the complexity of the whole algorithm. There's no multiplication by `n`. I removed that. That gets you n^6 as the answer.

Comment: @GiBiT09, Nikos C. : I'm still getting `O(n^4)`.

Comment: @Panther The total sum of all inner loop iterations is the running time of the algorithm. That sum translates to `n^6` (see the Wikipedia article I linked to) and I don't see any other mistakes in the answer.

Comment: @Panther Yep, I'm full of mistakes. The summation formula was wrong (since it was the sum of `i^3` and not just `i`.) I now used the correct one and... indeed this results in O(n^4) :-)

Comment: @GiBiT09 Turns out it's O(n^4). http://polysum.tripod.com/ shows the correct formula for calculating sums of powers.

Comment: Thanks for that link, pretty handy little reference

Answer (score 2):

If the in the inner loop `i^3` is for *i Bitwise Xor 3 (11)*
The O notation will be `O(n^2)`

If the in the inner loop `i^3` is for *i to the power of 3*
The O notation will be `O(n^4)`

In this case, the inner for loop will run

```
(1^3) + (2^3) + (3^3) + ... + (n^3) times
= (n^2 * (n+1)^2) / 4 times
so O(n^4)
```

Comment: I really think they meant i to the third power by `i^3`. You can't tell with pseudocode , but your `O(n^2)` doesn't mean "n bitwise xor 2", does it?

Comment: `i^3` means "i to the power of 3".

Comment: Yea it's i to the power of three

Comment: @GiBiT09 : I have updated the answer for `i to the power of 3` and `i Bitwise Xor 3` both